# Django - Create a table/model from two models

Tags: django

I have two models in Django;

Model 1 has information and an ID

Model 2 has specific more information about the ID in Model 1

Does anyone know how I could create another model, view and template (or the process) that takes the information from model 1 based on its ID and then links/binds it with the other detailed information for that ID from Model 2 creating another model/db for a detailed table/view of the combined models?

I have searched extensively but nothing is to clear and I am still learning but getting there slowly.

Thank you all and I hope your all safe.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to just create one model? You could use a OnetoOneField, so every instance of Model1 is linked to model 2 or vice versa

Comment: errorinpersona - Model 1 is constantly updating, its a continuous stream of data. I need to be able to see what information from Model 1's ID is linking to Model 2's ID and then split these out into separate tables. There are lots of different ID's. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I need it to be able to query Model 1 for updates as well. Im not really sure what I am asking is possible in Django.

Comment: Im open to try any suggestions and feedback if they work...

Comment: @Tealady would you be opposed to using a foreign key in Model 2 to reference Model 1? Then, when data comes in, you can easily reference and make the necessary changes? With that way, you can continue to use the view/template as before and easily reference the original data?

Comment: CoolestNerdIII - not at all. I can test anything and see if it works. The only issue I have is separation, ideally I would like to keep the data for specific ID's confined to one db/Model but I can try using the foreign key method. Would this be able to constantly check Model1(db1) for updates as the data comes in?

Comment: Would you be able to advise (generic) on  how I would achieve this?

Comment: @CoolestNerdIII happy to try anything as per my comments above.

Comment: and @errorinpersona happy to try anything

Comment: Anybody know how best to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should update your question, provide us your models, what you want to archive and where your issue is. It is still very unclear to me, why you cant use a one to one or a foreignkey field. What do you mean with a "constant stream of data"?